# UNIX: How to pick specific column value from result of sort?

Tags: shell, terminal, youtube-dl

I'm trying to sort the output of youtube-dl -F  by resolution and assign the format code of the highest res result to a variable to download the file using youtube-dl -f  . I'm able to sort the output of first step like so `youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=yKNxeF4KMsY | sort -b -r -k3`

With this example, the format code with highest video res is 43. How do I assign that value to a variable and use that further in a script I am writing?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the format code using this command:

```
format_code=$(youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=yKNxeF4KMsY | sort -b -r -k3 -n | head -1 | cut -d" " -f1)
```

This will sort sort the output based on the 3rd field (resolution), take the first line using the `head` command and then gets the first field (format code) using `cut`

```
$ echo $format_code
> 43
```

---

To get the desired output in `Python`:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output("youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKNxeF4KMsY | sort -b -r -k3 -n | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1", shell=True)

format_code = output.strip() # to remove the trailing '\n'
# or simply format_code = int(output) if you want an integer
```

And then the `format_code` variable will have the desired value which is `43` in this case.

Comment: Your solution does return the desired value when run as a shell command, however I'm trying to run it in a Python script and the following code is returning an error. Adding head to the pipe even without the modifier returns error and the command executes fun before head if I don't use it.

`best_qual = os.system("youtube-dl -F " + video_link + " | sort \-b \-r \-k3 \-n | grep \(best | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1")`

Error: 

Unknown option: 1
Usage: head [-options] <url>...

Comment: I thought you only needed it in the shell. Check the edit, I added the Python way ;)